# "Expression: vector iterator not deferencable" run-time error

Tags: c++, dereference

The following code inputs words and counts how many times each word appeared in the input. Then the program prints each word and corresponding frequency in the order from lowest to highest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    map<string, int> counters;
    map<int, vector<string> > freq;

    while (cin >> s)
        ++counters[s];

    map<string, int>::const_iterator it = counters.begin();
    for (it; it != counters.end(); ++it)
    {
        freq[it->second].push_back(it->first);
    }

    for (map<int, vector<string> >::const_iterator i = freq.begin();
        i != freq.end(); ++i)
    {
        vector<string>::const_iterator j = i->second.begin();
        cout << i->first << '\t' << *j;
        while (j != i->second.end())
        {
            ++j;
            cout << ", " << *j;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and runs, but whenever I enter all the words I need and enter EOF the following run-time error appears

> Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable

and then the following error also appears

> Standard C++ libraries out of range && 0

How to resolve it?

Comment: You should further explain how it runs (e.g. does it print all elements and THEN gives an error, or does it print no elements) and explain what you expect to happen (e.g. program prints all elements without an error)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because you are dereferencing `j` when it can point to `end`:

```
    cout << i->first << '\t' << *j;
                                ^----- HERE
```

And here's the change to fix it:

```
    if (j != i->second.end()) {
        cout << i->first << '\t' << *j;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    map<string, int> counters;
    map<int, vector<string> > freq;

    while (cin >> s)
        ++counters[s];

    map<string, int>::const_iterator it = counters.begin();
    for (it; it != counters.end(); ++it)
    {
        freq[it->second].push_back(it->first);
    }


    for (map<int, vector<string> >::const_iterator i = freq.begin();
        i != freq.end(); ++i)
    {
        vector<string>::const_iterator j = i->second.begin();
        cout << i->first << '\t';
        for (j; j != i->second.end(); ++j)
            cout << *j << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Still have no idea why "while" loo[ didn't work.

Comment: You should've incremented `j` only after using it.

Comment: `while` loop didn't work because you were incrementing `j` *before* printing it, instead of the other way around. And what's the point of that lonely first `j` in `for (j; j != i->second.end(); ++j)`? You have it in the earlier `for` loop too.